# Why there is link between parent node and child node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

1.I created Tweet and TweetLeaf nodes then create realatioships by using following code

```
MERGE (n:Tweet {id:'13084664', title:'A'})

MERGE (cl1:TweetLeaf {id:'13085170', title:'AB', reply_to:'13084664'})

MERGE (cl2:TweetLeaf {id:'13085179', title:'TESTING Team', reply_to:'13085170'})

MERGE (cl2:TweetLeaf {id:'13085352', title:'TESTING Team', reply_to:'13085170'})

MERGE (cl4:TweetLeaf {id:'13085443', title:'TESTING Team', retweet_to:'13085352'})

MERGE (cl5:TweetLeaf {id:'13085356', title:'TESTING Team', retweet_to:'13085352'})

//parent and leaf.....
MATCH (parent:Tweet)
MATCH (c:TweetLeaf)
WHERE NOT (c)-[:reply]->() 
AND parent.id = c.reply_to
WITH parent, c
MERGE (c)-[:reply_to]->(parent)
//RETURN c, parent

//leaf to leaf reply_to.....
MATCH (c1:TweetLeaf)-[]-()
WHERE exists (c1.reply_to)

MATCH (d1:TweetLeaf)
WHERE NOT (d1)-[]->() and exists (d1.reply_to)
AND c1.id = d1.reply_to

WITH c1, d1
MERGE (d1)-[:reply_to]->(c1)
//RETURN c1, d1

//leaf to leaf retweet_to....
MATCH (c2:TweetLeaf)
WHERE exists (c2.retweet_to)
AND NOT (c2)-[]->()

MATCH (d2:TweetLeaf)-[]->()
WHERE d2.id = c2.retweet_to

WITH c2, d2
MERGE (c2)-[:retweet_to]->(d2)
//RETURN c2, d2
```

2.The final result should be like the screenshot below
[image]

However, in my output there is not link between node A and node AB. The screenshot show my output graph
[image]

Comment: You code is working fine for me. How are you creating your output graph?

Comment: The code just exact same

Answer (score 0):

The query you used to generate your visualization apparently only returned `TweetLeaf` nodes, so the neo4j Browser only showed those nodes.

Instead, try using this query (which returns all paths of length 0 or 1 involving a `TweetLeaf` node):

```
MATCH p=(:TweetLeaf)-[*0..1]-()
RETURN p
```

*A path of length 0 would have no relationship, in case there are standalone `TweetLeaf` nodes. If you do not care about that edge case, then you can just use `p=(:TweetLeaf)--()` instead.*